# PHP Mysql - How do I Select top 6 results

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I got an search engine where users can search for different names.
The name of the table is "searched_names" and I wanna echo out the first 6 names ordered by most searched. There can example be ten people named Alex in the table and 8 John and 1 Peter then I would like it to echo it out like this.

```
Alex
John
Peter


SELECT * FROM names WHERE ... guess I'll use COUNT() somewhere
```

Comment: You need 2 additions sql commands. ORDER BY count... DESC LIMIT 6

Comment: how do you know what is most searched?  is there a column in the 'names' table, is there a different table with that info?

Answer (score 3):

Use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`

```
SELECT *
FROM names
WHERE ...
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 6
```

Answer (score 0):

he wants `ordered by most searched.`

```
SELECT * FROM names
ORDER BY col_containing_nb_of_search
limit 6
```